# Avoid spurious buffers with helm-find-file

Tags: helm, buffers, completion

I have `C-x C-f` bound to `helm-find-files`. Mostly this works really well, but if I hit `TAB` when there are no completions for an item (most often because I've fumble-fingered the directory or filename that I want completed) Helm unhelpfully creates a buffer with that mangled name.

Anyway to prevent that?

Comment: Helm must have some way of specifying whether reading a file or buffer name is lax or strict. If it uses (or you use) `completing-read` or `read-file-name`, they explicitly accept an argument for this purpose (called `REQUIRE-MATCH` for `completing-read` and `MUSTMATCH` for `read-file-name`).

Comment: ATM this is not possible without modifying `helm-find-file-or-marked`. In particular, see the `(find-file (substitute-in-file-name candidate))` line.

Answer (score 1):

Default behavior for TAB in *Helm* is to show a list of actions.
<kbd>C-j</kbd> is for completion.
If there are no completions, <kbd>C-j</kbd> creates a buffer(not a file until you save it).
Pressing <kbd>C-j</kbd> **again - kills that buffer**.

https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1810

A user asked about that previous behavior of TAB, completion in earlier versions:
https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1630

Comment: Thank you. I had a customization that rebound Tab to 'helm-execute-persistent-action (making it the same as C-j). I still find the behavior that it creates a buffer a little awkward, but knowing that Tab/C-j a second time will kill it is probably good enough.